# Closing scanner application/activity after a timeout

Tags: android, zxing

I am using IntentIntegrator to initiate a scanner (QR/Barcode - zxing) application. I have a requirement to close the scanner application after 30 seconds of start.

Scanner application is invoked through startActivityForResult. I am wondering if there is a way to get the reference of the activity started by "startActivityForResult", so that, I can use a timer and close the activity.

Android experts, please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only option here is to modify the ZXing code.

When you start the scanning activity, your app's activity will go to onPause() at which point you will need to cancel your timer(s), not start new ones.

Another thought might be to start a service, which starts a thread that kills the scanning activity after 30 seconds...but alas, you can't kill an activity from a service.

ZXing is open source, so you can pull it down, modify it and rebuild it.  There is a class called InactivityTimer.java that can be modified to finish the activity after x seconds.  Another option might be to add a broadcast receiver to the scanning manifest that will finish the scanning activity when a certain intent is received.

Basically, your package can only finish() activities defined in its manifest.  It can't kill activities in other packages...it's up to the user, or that app, to decide when to finish.